# Angularjs: eval() in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there anything equivalent to `$scope.$eval` in functionality to use in service? I want to get the object out of string representation in service.

Comment: Can you show what you are attempting?

Comment: why not to inject a `$scope` and use it in a service?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval although it is not equivalent. `$scope.$eval` evaluates angular expressions on a scope. it is questionable whether this makes sense in a service.

Comment: Davin, I am trying to make a plnkr of what I am doing. Basically, the string is created by select input element (where the option is object), which I am passing to service to process (could do in controller, but there are lot of code which I like to move to service). I am also thinking how to use Json, instead of string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my use case, angular.fromJson worked.

In my case, string was created by angular in a option element.

Answer (score 2):

Inject `$rootScope` to service dependencies and use `$rootScope.$eval`.